# How is called this peculiar rounded segment display system?

Tags: lcd, display

There are a number of industrial displays which use 23-segment columns to show semi-rounded alphanumeric characters and simple icons. An example photo:

[image: segment]

I cannot find anything about this system, like its name or a concrete product.

Comment: It may not have a name : it looks like a custom product with segments designed to took reasonably good on European languages. I've certainly never seen small LED based devices like you can for n-character 7 segment displays, for example. You can have custom LCDs and possibly electroluminescent (EL) made to your own drawings. Maybe that's what happened here. (The design may be copyrighted or patented; search for patents from the manufacturer)

Comment: What famous painting is [this](http://www.slate.com/features/2014/05/simple_quiz/quizzes/paintings/img/paintings_01_small.jpg) from? Or maybe [this one](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQgZfHMSOYHo7p3jlhQEgGWMxRWDG73hyvunw&usqp=CAU)? Do you see my point?

Comment: @Brian Yes it might be a proprietary solution. It would explain why I have found nothing about it.

Comment: @Andy Not quite. The image shows a complete column to the right. Do you mean that it is not any common standard like the sixteen-segment display?

Comment: @Andyaka the second one is Leonardo DaVinci's Venus. - it's not necessarily a hopeless question for everyone.

Comment: My point is that the pictures I showed are parts of world class famous paintings that even a non art-student might be able to recognize. The display in the picture is obscure else why not mention where it is from and, if this is known then, why not try contacting the owners if it's that important.

Comment: The first one is ["Girl with a Pearl Earring"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girl_with_a_Pearl_Earring) by Vermeer.  The second is ["The Birth of Venus"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birth_of_Venus) by Botticelli.  Both recognizable to a non-expert (me) even in the extremely cropped versions. In the same way the cropped images in the question are recognizable  to anyone who has seen them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in your question shows a text in German, and is either from a bus or streetcar.

[This](https://www.aditech-lcd.de/de/Bus-9945-277.html) German company makes LCD displays for buses.  The LCD panels appear to be custom made - either ADITECH orders them made that way, or makes them in house.

In any case, they are LCD panels with custom drivers for the unusual "pixel" shapes.

The shapes used in the LCD pixels are based on shapes used in earlier ["flip dot" displays.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-disc_display)

I have been on buses that used the mechanical flip dots, but that was long ago (more than 20 years.)

If you want that kind of panel, you'll have either order them from an LCD panel manufacturer, or buy a used bus display (if you just want it for a hobby kind of thing.)